# printing a block of text that matches a pattern

Tags: text-processing, aix

Using just shell script, how to search a text file and list all whole blocks of lines that has inside some text (simple grep criteria).

The text file has blocks of lines separated by `"-----------------"` (precisely, each block start with `"\n\n\n--------------------"`... about 50 chars "-").

A sample could be:

```
-------------------------------
Abracadabra, blablablalbalba
blablablabla, banana



-------------------------------
Text, sample text, sample text, sample text
Text, sample text, sample text, sample text
Text, sample text, sample text, sample text
Text, sample text, sample text, sample text


-------------------------------  
Text, sample text, sample text, sample text
banana. Sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text
Text, sample text, sample text, sample text
```

Lets consider the word "banana" the search criteria. So, the blocks listed would be:

```
-------------------------------
Abracadabra, blablablalbalba
blablablabla, banana


-------------------------------
Text, sample text, sample text, sample text
banana. Sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text
Text, sample text, sample text, sample text
```

**EDIT:**

Testing answers to try awk, like: `awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n------------"}/INFO/{print}'` where INFO is what was searched for. I cannot get the whole block. So, follows a real sample and the result:

**A REAL SAMPLE** (including the first 3 new lines):

```
-------------------------------------------------
Diretório separado do nome o arquivo: adis, IWZLM (/home/interx/adis/src/IWZLM.SRC)
Gerando rotina em linguagem C:
(yla5 adis IWZLM -if)
.INFO =>Rotina BLOQUEADA (status 'M'): Geracao ignorada (use -is para ignorar checagem do status)

[  OK-I ] IWZLM (adis) - Lista lay: Geracao ignorada do codigo em C.



-------------------------------------------------
Diretório separado do nome d arquivo: adis, ADISA (/home/interx/adis/src/ADISA.SRC)
Gerando rotina em linguagem C:
(yla5 adis ADISA -if)
.ERRO: Falha inesperada

Compilando o programa:
(ycomp adis ADISA -exe adis/exe/ADISA.temp.exe )
adis/exe/ADISA.temp.exe => adis/exe/ADISA

[  OK   ] ADISA (adis) - Menu A : Gerada e compilada com sucesso.



-------------------------------------------------
Diretório separado do nome o arquivo: adis, ADISD1 (/home/interx/adis/src/ADISD1.SRC)
Gerando rotina em linguagem C:
(yla5 adis ADISD1 -if)
.ATENCAO: Definicao nao localizada

Compilando o programa:
(ycomp adis ADISD1 -exe adis/exe/ADISD1.temp.exe )
adis/exe/ADISD1.temp.exe => adis/exe/ADISD1

[  OK   ] ADISD1 (adis) - Menu : Gerada e compilada com sucesso.
```

I cannot get the whole block, just the line containing "INFO", like a ordinary grep, either setting or not ORS:

```
$ cat file  | awk 'BEGIN{RS="\n------------"}/INFO/{print}' 
.INFO =>Rotina BLOQUEADA (status 'M'): Geracao ignorada (use -is para ignorar checagem do status)
```

**NOTES:**
It is the awk from AIX 7.1, not gawk.

Comment: The first block in the sample does not technically start with "\n\n\n---..."

Comment: Yes. Just in the sample.

Comment: is perl an option?

Comment: No. Perl isn't an option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
awk '
{
  if (/-------------------------------------------------/) {
    if (hold ~ /INFO/) {
      print hold;
    }
    hold="";
  } else {
    hold=hold "\n" $0
  }
} 
END {
  if (hold ~ /INFO/) {
    print hold;
  }
}' file
```

This uses a 'hold'ing variable (ala sed) to accumulate lines between separated blocks; once a new block (or EOF) is encountered, print the held value only if it matches the /INFO/ pattern.

<sub>(re: the older comments, I deleted my previous inadequate awk and perl answers to clean up this answer)</sub>

Comment: (assuming GNU awk or mawk)

Comment: consider my edits

Comment: That is the approach I'm working now and getting success. Of course, my script is a little bit different but the essence is the same. That works.

Answer (score 4):

Should be quite easy with `awk` if you don't need all `-` in the output:

```
awk -vRS='----' '/banana/{print}' file
```

alternatively `pcregrep`:

```
pcregrep -M '^-+[^-]*banana[^-]*' file
```

Comment: (assuming GNU awk or mawk)

Comment: Could my unhappy results be the awk AIX behavior ? (see my edits)

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind the missing leading empty lines, here's a `sed` solution:

```
sed '/---/b end                      # if line matches pattern branch to : end
//!{H                                # if it doesn't match, append to hold space
$!d                                  # and if not on the last line, delete it
$b end                               # if it's the last line branch to : end
}
: end                                # label end
x                                    # exchange hold buffer and pattern space
/PATTERN/!d                          # if pattern space doesn't match, delete it
' <infile
```

Comment: You can also do this on one line like so: `sed -e '/---/b end' -e '//!{H' -e '$!d;$b end' -e '}; : end' -e 'x; /PATTERN/!d' infile`  (I've found that many people appreciate the one line versions of complex `sed` commands.)

Answer (score 0):

One of the things is that for passing regular expressions, when backslash is involved it must be escaped. it was tested against the input provided as **A REAL SAMPLE**

> parrsel code

```
#!/usr/bin/nawk -f
BEGIN{ORS=RS="\n\n\n"}   # the record separator is considering three \n
$0~var1{print}           # when record contains var1 print record
```

> Execution

```
## the pattern is passed as var1 and is considering the occurrence of OK as a word
parrsel -v var1=paragraphs -vvar1='\\<OK\\>' data

-------------------------------------------------
Diretório separado do nome o arquivo: adis, IWZLM (/home/interx/adis/src/IWZLM.SRC)
Gerando rotina em linguagem C:
(yla5 adis IWZLM -if)
.INFO =>Rotina BLOQUEADA (status 'M'): Geracao ignorada (use -is para ignorar checagem do status)

[  OK-I ] IWZLM (adis) - Lista lay: Geracao ignorada do codigo em C.



-------------------------------------------------
Diretório separado do nome d arquivo: adis, ADISA (/home/interx/adis/src/ADISA.SRC)
Gerando rotina em linguagem C:
(yla5 adis ADISA -if)
.ERRO: Falha inesperada

Compilando o programa:
(ycomp adis ADISA -exe adis/exe/ADISA.temp.exe )
adis/exe/ADISA.temp.exe => adis/exe/ADISA

[  OK   ] ADISA (adis) - Menu A : Gerada e compilada com sucesso.
```