# Parsing a file using unix commands

Tags: shell-script, text-processing

I am new to Unix and I have a log file which I need to analyze. Below is my sample log file:

```
Container:container_e182_1234
=============================
LogType:container-localizer-syslog
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:3000
Log Contents:
20/06/25 12:19:33 INFO datasources.FileScanRDD: Reading File path: hdfs://bpaiddev/dev/data/warehouse/clean/falcon/ukc/
20/06/25 12:19:39 ERROR Exception found
java.io.Exception:Not initiated
    at.apache.java.org.Exception(132)
20/06/25 12:19:40 INFO executor.EXECUTOR: Finished task 18.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 18),18994 bytes result sent to driver.
20/06/25 12:20:41 WARN Warning as the node is accessed without started
 
LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

Container:container_e182_1234
=============================
LogType:container-localizer-syslog
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:
    
LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:3000
Log Contents:

LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:
```

Expected output

```
stderr
Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
3000
20/06/25 12:19:39 ERROR Exception found
java.io.Exception:Not initiated
    at.apache.java.org.Exception(132)
20/06/25 12:20:41 WARN Warning as the node is accessed without started
```

The output must contain only the ERROR and WARN and also the other details as mentioned above

Log file:

```
Container:container_e182_1234
=============================
LogType:container-localizer-syslog
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:45 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:3000
Log Contents:
20/06/25 12:19:33 INFO datasources.FileScanRDD: Reading File path: hdfs://bpaiddev/dev/data/warehouse/clean/falcon/ukc/masked_data/parquet/FRAUD_CUSTOMER_INFORMATION/rcd_crt_dttm_yyyymmdd=20200523/part-0042-ed52abc2w.c000.snapp.parquet, range:0-27899, partition values :[20200523]
20/06/25 12:19:39 ERROR Exception found
java.io.Exception:Not initated
    at.apache.java.org........
20/06/25 12:19:40 INFO executor.EXECUTOR: Finished task 18.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 18),18994 bytes result sent to driver.
20/06/25 12:20:41 WARN Warning as the node is accessed without started
 
LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:

Container:container_e182_1234
=============================
LogType:container-localizer-syslog
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:
    
LogType:stderr
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:3000
Log Contents:
20/06/25 12:19:33 INFO datasources.FileScanRDD: Reading File path: hdfs://bpaiddev/dev/data/warehouse/clean/falcon/ukc/masked_data/parquet/FRAUD_CUSTOMER_INFORMATION/rcd_crt_dttm_yyyymmdd=20200523/part-0042-ed52abc2w.c000.snapp.parquet, range:0-27899, partition values :[20200523]
20/06/25 12:19:34 INFO executor.EXECUTOR: Finished task 18.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 18),18994 bytes result sent to driver.
     
LogType:stdout
Log Upload Time :Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
LogLength:0
Log Contents:
```

How to do this ? Please help me to solve this issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You asked [the same question on the main SE site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62816678/analysing-log-file-in-python), but for Python rather than Awk. I don't think you're likely to get a different result here. If an [existing solution](https://www.ubuntupit.com/best-linux-log-viewer-and-log-file-management-tools/) won't work for you, try something in your preferred language and ask a more specific question when you get stuck.

Comment: I think using awk I can get a solution which I can use in Python. So I have asked here.No I don't want to use tools . I just need to analyze them using code. I have asked for different approach here

Comment: I got stuck in the above mentioned area.  So I have asked for the solution .

Comment: I thought of going with that approach and I found using awk I can easily create a new file. From that file I can easily analyze them

Comment: It looks like you could first select the blocks with ERROR and WARN with something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19257597/find-specific-pattern-and-print-complete-text-block-using-awk-or-sed Then you would just need to remove the beginning of each line up through `:`.

Comment: But so far you haven't shown us anything except your input. Give it a try and post your code so we have something to start with, and I think you're more likely to get to the solution.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need awk?
You can just use `sed` like this: `sed -n 's/^.*LogType:\(.*\)$/\1/p; s/^.*Log Upload Time :\(.*\)/\1/p; s/^.*LogLength:\(.*\)$/\1/p; s/^.*\(ERROR\|WARN\).*$/\0/p' file`.
If not, I would write it as an answer.

Comment: Thank you I will try the above mentioned link. Yeah I would like to include my code but this is the beginning part So I am out of thoughts. Sure I will try with the above mentioned link .Thanks again for your guidance!

Comment: No I can use sed also .Thank you Clemente. Post as a solution .Will try that

Comment: Does `stdout` have some content that we need to worry about?

Comment: No there is no content there mate! I just need the stderr logType

Comment: Is this a tab character at the start of each line or this a typo?

Comment: No No it's just a typo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sed` for the same purpose with the following one-liner (assuming your file is called `file`):

```
sed -n 's/^.*LogType:\(stderr\)$/\1/p; s/^.*Log Upload Time :\(.*\)/\1/p; s/^.*LogLength:\(.*\)$/\1/p; s/^.*\(ERROR\|WARN\).*$/\0/p' file
```

Then you can save its output somewhere using a redirection (`>`) to another file.

Split up to multiple lines for easier reading:

```
sed -n -e 's/^.*LogType:\(stderr\)$/\1/p' \
       -e 's/^.*Log Upload Time :\(.*\)/\1/p' \
       -e 's/^.*LogLength:\(.*\)$/\1/p' \
       -e 's/^.*\(ERROR\|WARN\).*$/\0/p' file
```

**Update**

The solution above doesn't exclude blocks which are not of the 'LogType:stderr' as requested by the OP; there is required non-local infomation (not in the same line), which is not amenable to treat with `sed` alone.

The following script, which uses both `awk` and `sed`, (with the `awk` part inspired by [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255140/printing-a-block-of-text-that-matches-a-pattern)), does the job:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=$1
awk '{
  if($0 ~ /LogType/){
    if(hold ~ /LogType:stderr/){
      print hold;
    }
    hold=$0
  }else{
    hold=hold "\n" $0
  }
}END{
  if(hold ~ /LogType:stderr/){
    print hold
  }
}' $file | sed -n -e 's/^.*LogType:\(stderr\)$/\1/p' \
                 -e 's/^.*Log Upload Time :\(.*\)/\1/p' \
                 -e 's/^.*LogLength:\(.*\)$/\1/p'       \
                 -e 's/^.*\(ERROR\|WARN\).*$/\0/p'
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110553/discussion-on-answer-by-giuseppe-clemente-parsing-a-file-using-unix-commands).

Answer (score 1):

I am able to do it using a short script.  The original log is contained in the file `logdata`.

```
#!/bin/bash

tmpfile="/tmp/$0.$$"

sed -n '/stderr/,/^ *$/p' logdata > "$tmpfile"
sed -n 's/^.*LogType:\(.*\)/\1/p
        s/^.*Log Upload Time :\(.*\)/\1/p
        s/^.*LogLength:\(.*\)/\1/p' "$tmpfile"
grep -E "(ERROR|WARN)" "$tmpfile"
rm "$tmpfile"
```

First, we extract the `stderr` block into a temporary file.  Then, take out the two fields and then, `grep` the error and warning.  I was trying to connect the last two steps using `tee` but did not succeed.

I could do it without the temporary file by

```
sed -n '/stderr/,/^ *$/p' logdata | \
sed -n 's/^.*LogType:\(.*\)/\1/p
        s/^.*Log Upload Time :\(.*\)/\1/p
        s/^.*LogLength:\(.*\)/\1/p
        /ERROR/p
        /WARN/p'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate!  But  I was able to get  only the error/warning statements '20/06/25 12:19:34 ERROR executor.EXECUTOR: Finished task 18.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 18),18994 bytes result sent to driver'. I was not able to get  the other details like LogType, Log Length

Comment: Do you have the missed fields not starting in column 1?  If so, you can change the regex by inserting `.*` after `^`, for example, `s/^.*LogType:\(.*\)/\1/p`.  I'll fix the answers.

Comment: Thank you I got the answer .But it is also giving the stdout also in addition to stderr . Can you check with that please ?

Comment: Yes, you have spaces in your blank line before `stdout`.  You can remove that or look for it.  Modifying the answer for that as well.  All I do is to replace `^$` with `^ *$`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your inputs!

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk '
  /LogType:stderr/ || (p && /Log( Upload Time|Length)/){
    p=1                    # set flag for stderr block
    sub(/^[^:]+:/, "")     # replace content before `:` including `:`
    print                  # print (modified) line
  }
  p && / (WARN|ERROR) /{ 
    sub(/^[^0-9]*/, "")    # remove unknown prefix
    print
  }  
  /LogType:stdout/{ exit } # exit the script
' file
```

Comment: Thanks Freddy for the code. But should I add anything to this code because  currently it is not giving any output .

Comment: Not really. `file` should be your logfile, that's all. Does it work if you copy & paste the example from your question above (again) into a file?

Comment: Yeah I tried that but it is not showing any output . It runs without any error but gives no output

Comment: Can you try `awk '/^LogType:stderr/ || /^Log( Upload Time|Length)/' file` just for testing? If that doesn't print anything, there's something wrong with the logfile format.

Comment: Yes It doesn't print anything mate

Comment: Can you upload a sample somewhere?

Comment: You need to add `.*` after `^` as I suggested in my answer.

Comment: Removed `^` and added a `sub()` for the `WARN` and `ERROR` lines. It's still not clear how your lines start (whitespace, tab?), please try again.

Comment: Thanks Freddy I am able to get the output! But it also prints  the logUpload time  and loglength of every Type which is coming after the stderr. How to remove that ?

Comment: I can only guess since your input is different and replaced the last line of the script. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

Using `GNU sed` and utilizing it's extended regex mode.

```
sed -Ee '
  /LogType:stderr/,/^\s*$/!d
  /Log Contents:/,/^\s*$/!{
    s/^[^:]*://;b
  }
  /\s(ERROR|WARN)\s/!d
' logfile
```

**Explanation:**

- We partition the file into range (log type to blank line) and then subdivide each range into (pre log contents and post)
- In the subrange pre block, strip away till the first colon character. But don't print it yet since we don't know as of now whether an error or warning is present in the post block of the subrange. So we hold it in the hold space.
- When we reach the post block in the subrange we detect the error or warning lines. Then retrieve the hold and print it now.

**Results:**

```
stderr
Thu Jun 25 12:24:52 +0100 2020
3000
20/06/25 12:19:39 ERROR Exception found
20/06/25 12:20:41 WARN Warning as the node is accessed without started
```

In case you need also the line numbers of the error / warning messages, then use the below sed commands which are modified from  above:

```
sed -Ee '
  /LogType:stderr/,/^\s*$/!d
  /Log Contents:/,/^\s*$/!{
    s/^[^:]*://;b
  }
  /\s(ERROR|WARN)\s/!d
  p;=;d
' logfile |
sed -Ee '/\s(ERROR|WARN)\s/N;s/\n/ on line #/'
```

You can use other tools like awk n perl to do this job also:
Note : remove trailing spaces from blank lines first.

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    RS = "\n\n"              
    FS = "\nLog Contents:\n" 
    OFS = "\n"               
    ORS = OFS                
    spc = "[[:blank:]]" 
    str = "(ERROR|WARN)" 
    pat = spc str spc 
  }
  /^LogType:stderr/ &&
  NF == 2 {
    p = $1; gsub(/(^|\n)[^:]+:/, "\n", p);sub(/./, "", p) 
    N = split($2, a, /\n/)
    print p
    for ( i=1; i<=N; i++ ) 
      if ( a[i] ~ pat ) 
        print a[i]
  }
' logfile
```

```
perl -F'/^Log\hContents:$/m,$_,2' -00 -ne '
  next if ! /\ALogType:stderr$/m;
  (my $pre = $F[0])=~ s/.*?://gm;
  my $post = join "\n",
    grep { /\s(?:ERROR|WARN)/ }
    split /\n/, $F[1];
  print($pre,$post);
' logfile
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Rakesh for your support ! I am able to get the result

Comment: Hi Rakesh, I was just able to print only I block of stderr . Why is it like that ? Should I make any changes to the code ?

Comment: Yes I have shared in the question

Comment: Ok fine Now I understand the code. Also I think only the first line of the error message not the other lines of the particular error message .Is that possible to do that ? I have updated my ERROR  log in the question. Suppose we have multiple line for a ERROR message , Will this code work ?

Comment: Sorry my bad! I actually took a part of my log file and posted .Sorry Rakesh! I will update in the question

Comment: Yes I have added. If there is no  ERROR /WARN messages it leaves them out. It just prints the stderr which has exactly these messages which was also my requirement.

Comment: No mate It prints only the first line of the ERROR message and also prints the second stderr block which has no content in it. Your previous code did well compared to this.

Comment: I have put my expected output in the  above question .

Comment: It is printing only the first line of the ERROR not the next line of error. (i.e) it is printing 'ERROR exception found' not the next lines of that error message (i.e) java.io.exception....