# How do I extract portion of a log file given the delimiters and a word contained in between?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk, sed

I have a log file and I need to extract the sections related to a specific event. I performed something similar before but easier with the "sed" command.

The task I've been trying to solve is the following.
I need to extract all the portions of text in the file starting with the word "BEGIN" included and ending before the next "BEGIN" where it is included a specific *word* identifying a table in my database.
I need help with the usage of the *sed* command.

The task can be summarized in "search between all occurrences delimited by *Start* and *End* containing the word *word*"

The text looks like something like this:

```
BEGIN
...
something here
something here containing the desired "word"
something here
...
COMMIT
BEGIN 
.
.
.
COMMIT
BEGIN
```

And I want to obtain all the occurrencies conaining "word" as this:

```
BEGIN
...
something here containing the desired "word"
...
COMMIT
```

Comment: Is every BEGIN END section in its own line, or are the multiple of them inside one line

Comment: Does this answer your question? [printing a block of text that matches a pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255140/printing-a-block-of-text-that-matches-a-pattern) - This [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255145/123460) uses `awk` to a) select text blocks between START and END keywords and b) only prints the block if the MATCH keyword is found.

Comment: Please also show the expected output you want to get. Please confirm if the `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` lines will always be separate lines as shown in the example. Can there be more than one line between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`? Please [edit] your question to add requested information, don't use comments to answer. Additional requirements should also be added to the question.

Comment: maybe `awk 'BEGIN{RS="BEGIN"} /word/' inputfile` or `awk 'BEGIN{RS="(\n*COMMIT)?\n*BEGIN\n*"} /word/' inputfile` or `awk 'BEGIN{RS="(COMMIT\n*)?BEGIN\n*"} /word/' inputfile`?

Comment: @Fiximan looks like it does. I'll try. Thank you so much!